# C# class method does work when called from C#, but not when called from VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have the following utility class, created in C#.

```
public class ObjectMapper<TSource, TTarget>
{
    private Collection<Action<TSource, TTarget>> _mappings =
                    new Collection<Action<TSource, TTarget>>();


    public void AddMapping(Action<TSource, TTarget> action)
    {
        _mappings.Add(action);
    }

    public void ApplyMappings(TSource source, TTarget target)
    {
        foreach (var mapping in _mappings)
        {
            mapping(source, target);
        }
    }
}
```

I can use this class to copy properties from one object to another. I know that there are other alternatives like AutoMapper, but that is not part of the scope of my question.

When I use this class from a C# project, everything works fine. Unit tests pass etc. Below is an example of usage of this class from C# (apologies for the dutch namings).

```
        // Arrange
        // initialiseer auteur
        Auteur auteur = new Auteur
        {
            Achternaam = "Loon",
            Tussenvoegsel = "van",
            Initialen = "P."
        };

        // initialiseer boek
        Boek boek = new Boek
        {
            Auteur = auteur,
            Titel = "Ravelijn",
            Isbn13 = "9789025857813",
            Druk = 1,
            UitgaveJaar = 2011,
            Uitgever = "Leopold B.V."
        };

        // initialiseer mapper
        ObjectMapper<Boek, BibliotheekItem> mapper = new ObjectMapper<Boek, BibliotheekItem>();
        mapper.AddMapping((bk, bib) => bib.Auteur = boek.Auteur.Initialen +
                                                    (string.IsNullOrEmpty(boek.Auteur.Tussenvoegsel) ? " " : " " + boek.Auteur.Tussenvoegsel + " ") +
                                                    boek.Auteur.Achternaam);
        mapper.AddMapping((bk, bib) => bib.Titel = boek.Titel);
        mapper.AddMapping((bk, bib) => bib.Uitgave = boek.Uitgever + ", " + boek.UitgaveJaar.ToString());
        mapper.AddMapping((bk, bib) => bib.Type = BibliotheekItem.ItemType.BOEK);
        mapper.AddMapping((bk, bib) => bib.Id = "ISBN13:" + bk.Isbn13);

        // Act
        BibliotheekItem bi = new BibliotheekItem();
        mapper.ApplyMappings(boek, bi);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual("P. van Loon", bi.Auteur, false);
        Assert.AreEqual("Leopold B.V., 2011", bi.Uitgave, false);
```

When I try to use this class from a VB.Net project, the properties of my target object remain empty.
I really haven't been able to find the cause of that.

```
Dim bron As New Bron
    Dim doel As New Doel

    bron.Prop1 = "Waarde 1"
    bron.Prop2 = "Waarde 2"

    Dim mapper As ObjectMapper(Of Bron, Doel) = New bogaarts.algemeen.ObjectMapper(Of Bron, Doel)
    mapper.AddMapping(Function(b, d) d.Prop1 = b.Prop1)
    mapper.AddMapping(Function(b, d) d.Prop2 = b.Prop2)
    mapper.PasMappingsToe(bron, doel)

    MessageBox.Show(doel.Prop1 & " : " & doel.Prop2)
```

Does anybody have an idea what I'm overlooking?

Comment: The C# code is adding different mappings to the VB.Net code, that could be relevant.

Comment: `apologies for the dutch namings` thats why you should ALWAYS program in english IMHO ;-)...

Comment: Have a look at [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266563/do-non-english-words-increase-the-probability-of-receiving-downvotes/) to get a rough guess how non-english naming influences the behaviour of the common StackOverflow user.

Comment: @ChrFin, I can't agree with you more. Unfortunately my company prefers English and it looks like I lost the battle ;)

Comment: @Jodrell Both examples use different classes for source and target. As a result, the mappings also are different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In VB You're creating a **function** (and not a `Sub`).  This means that it will have a return type.  The return type is being inferred as a `Boolean`, and `d.Prop2 = b.Prop2` is being interpreted as an equality check rather than an assignment operation.  That boolean return value is then being discarded to conform to the signature of `AddMapping`, which requires an `Action`.

Comment: and that is one good reason why assign and equality should not be overloaded.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. I already tried to use an Action instead of a Function, but have not yet been able to find out what the correct syntax is. Can you please provide me with an example?

Comment: @BjörnBoxstart I already told you, you need to use `Sub` instead of `Function`.

Comment: @Servy Sorry, I missed that. Your solution works like a charm! I thought that I would actually need to do something with the 'Action' type. I will mark your solution as THE solution.